# Does GWT have richtextbox which show RTF type data?

Tags: gwt, richtextbox, rtf, html-editor, rich-text-editor

I'm using [GWT Richtextbox](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText), But this widget shows values which are simple text or HTML formatted. 
Is there any way to show RTF data in a GWT-Richtext or GWT-htmlEditor widget? Or is there a widget in other GWT libraries which will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. About year ago we wanted to develop rtf browser on client side and we failed.
There is no GWT-Rtf libraries. You could try to find something written in javascript and then wrap it with JSNI, but I haven't seen such library as well. Someone told me that it might be possible with Activex, but we haven't even tried this method.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? If you want to share documents with an RTF editor like, say, Microsoft Word, you should check to see if that editor can also work with HTML. I know that MS Word can edit HTML.

Alternatively, you might consider transposing RTF into HTML and back again on the server side. There are several Java libraries out there for doing that, and I believe that [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) is one of them.

Comment: I have RTF data on the database, I will show it in internet browser and user will edit it. So I convert RTF to HTML and use it. But When HTML is used, multiple spaces is ignored in EDITOR. So text format lost and user don't see which typed before saved.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a matter of replacing normal spaces with non-breaking spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in the editor. You could do that on the fly, intercepting key presses with a KeyDownHandler (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasKeyDownHandlers.html)

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not this. No problem while user typing, problem is occured when the stored data get from DB and put to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RTFEditorKit in combination with HTMLEditorKit to convert between the two server-side or in an applet.  This way you can use GWT's rich text editor and output or input RTF.

```
public static String getHtmlFromRtf(InputStream fi){
    Writer sOut = new StringWriter();
    DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();                  
    HTMLEditorKit htmlKit = new HTMLEditorKit();                  
    RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();

    try
    {
        rtf.read( fi, doc, 0 );
        htmlKit.write(sOut, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sOut.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this methods problem is multiple spaces. GWT's richtext editor ignore multiple spaces.

Comment: change them to &nbsp; in the html.

Comment: This is not easy as seen, replace method change <p style="sd"> to <p&nbsp;style="sd">, This is not acceptable. En ıntelligent replace method requires.